# Avoid "value can be null" warning for extension method

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, dart-analyzer

I am using an extension on `Iterable` that adds the following two methods

```
extension MyIterableExt<T> on Iterable<T> {
  bool get isEmptyOrNull => this == null || this.isEmpty;
  bool get isNotEmptyOrNull => this != null && this.isNotEmpty;
}
```

This works as I expected, but when I try to use it in statements where the receiver can be null, I get a warning in IntelliJ. For example, the following code works and prints `true`:

```
List<String> x;
print('${x?.reversed.isEmptyOrNull}');
```

Is there any way I can make the Dart Analyzer understand that the extension checks if `this == null` and thus not show the warning?

###### Please note that I do not want to have to add suppression directives to every file or line where I use this extension!

I know I can add `// ignore_for_file: can_be_null_after_null_aware` or `// ignore: can_be_null_after_null_aware` to make the warning go away, but what I'm looking for is a way to make the Dart Analyzer understand that the warning for this particular extension method is not needed.

This is in a non null-safe project, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

you can make Iterable Nullable

```
extension MyIterableExt<T> on Iterable<T>? {
  bool get isEmptyOrNull => this == null || this!.isEmpty;
  bool get isNotEmptyOrNull => this != null && this!.isNotEmpty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make extension base on `Iterable?` is the way, if you have to find something to disable the warning but not want to change the code then im sorry cause i never do that before.

```dart
void main() {
  Iterable? a = [];
  Iterable b = ['1', '2', '3'];
  
  print('a.isEmptyOrNull: ${a.isEmptyOrNull}');
  print('b.isEmptyOrNull: ${b.isEmptyOrNull}');
  print('a.isNotEmptyOrNull: ${a.isNotEmptyOrNull}');
  print('b.isNotEmptyOrNull: ${b.isNotEmptyOrNull}');
}

extension on Iterable? {
  bool get isEmptyOrNull => this == null || this!.isEmpty;
  bool get isNotEmptyOrNull => this != null && this!.isNotEmpty;
}
```

result

```
a.isEmptyOrNull: true
b.isEmptyOrNull: false
a.isNotEmptyOrNull: false
b.isNotEmptyOrNull: true
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the [Flutter docs](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety), you should be able to add a comment at the top of your code that will essentially disable null safety checks:

```dart
// @dart=2.9
import 'src/my_app.dart';

main() {
  //...
}
```

You should be able to put that comment at the top of any specific file you want this behavior. It doesn't have to be in your "main" file.

Comment: I clarified the question a bit. I know I can suppress warnings by putting directives in every file where I use this extension, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want to keep the warnings where they make sense, but for these extension methods the warning doesn't make sense.

Comment: I didn't test this, but I would assume that if you add the comment directive to the extension file, it will apply that only to the contents of that file, which should affect any other file using the code within it.

Comment: FYI, I didn't downvote your answer, someone else did. But nevertheless, in my opinion it's up to each and everyone to decide for themselves if an answer provides value _in regard to the question_, and up- or downvote as they please.